# C# To return File Path's Last Written Date

Tags: c#, blueprism

I have an action in Blueprism that will bring back all files from a base directory (including sub folders). I also need to return the last written date. Is this possible?

```
public DataTable Get_Files_ALL(string Path, string Pattern, bool Recursive)
{
DataTable Paths = new DataTable("Paths");
DataColumn PathId = new DataColumn("Path", typeof(String));
Paths.Columns.Add(PathId);

var String_Array = new string[] {};

if (Recursive)
    String_Array = Directory.GetFiles(Path, Pattern, System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
else
    String_Array = Directory.GetFiles(Path, Pattern, System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

int count = String_Array.Length;

foreach (string Path_Array in String_Array)
{
    DataRow row1 = Paths.NewRow();
    row1["Path"] = Path_Array;
    Paths.Rows.Add(row1);
};

return Paths;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to get the last modified data of a particular file:

```
System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(path)
```

Comment: Thanks, could you call out where in the code it needs to go?